# SMB3 support in old Linux kernel

Tags: linux, samba

How can I find out whether or not Linux kernel 2.6.39.4 and mount.cifs version 4.5 supports SMB3?

Comment: A calendar is sufficient, I think. That ancient kernel predates SMB 3.0....

Comment: Probably relevant: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/SMB3_kernel_status#Introduction

Answer (score 0):

From the [SMB3 kernel status](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/SMB3_kernel_status#Introduction) article on the Samba wiki:

> The minimum version for use of the Linux kernel SMB3 support is kernel
> version 3.12 (or backport of cifs.ko module version 2.02 or later) but
> kernel version 4.11 or later is recommended due to the addition of the
> SMB3 share encryption security feature.